# How to change the value of cell automatically when meet some criteria in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am working on creating result key in template and I have just one last task that I cannot figure out. Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish.

If A3 = Monday, Thursday, Friday or Sunday, when the people key in less than or equal 0.05 at the range A7:A30, the value will change to 0.01 automatically and if the value is more than 0.05, the value will remain the same. If A3 = Tuesday, Wednesday or Saturday, the value at the range will remain the same, not matter what value it is.

Is that any script or formula in google sheet can do this kind of task?

This picture below is showing the template.

[Key in template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHGSK.png)

Comment: Need to consider if A3 is other values or blank?

Comment: Yes, A3 can be blank and other values. In this situation, the workers will need to key in the day in cell A3 first. After that, they need to enter the result in A7:A30, once the value that they entered is equal or less than 0.05, the value will automatically change to 0.01. If the value of cell A3 is other than Monday, Thursday, Friday or Sunday, the value will not be change and if the value is more than 0.05, the value also remain the same

Comment: i tried the formula but it is not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should no quote numbers (`0.05` `0.01`)
- You `return` in `if(value <= 0.05 & value !="")` so only the first matching row would be overwritten
- `targetSunday != "Monday"` typo
- `targetDate` condition outside `for` loop would look smarter
- `row` (actually arrayIndex or rowIndex) starts from `0`

```js
 function changeValue(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var targetDate = sheet.getRange('A3').getValue();
  if(!["Monday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday"].includes(targetDate)) { return; }

  var targetRange = sheet.getRange('A7:A30');
  var values = targetRange.getValues();
  for(var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    var value = values[row][0];
    if(value <= 0.05 & value !="") {
      value = 0.01;
      values[row][0] = value;
    }    
  }
  targetRange.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Updated. Please make sure you put it in `B7`

Comment: I already post my code and what i want is something that overwrite the value in the cells not to open a new column for it.

Comment: Modified based on your code. Please check.

Comment: The code can be executed but do nothing on the value and do not overwrite

Comment: Have you registered `function onEdit() { changeValue(); }`?

Answer (score 0):

Is that something like this?

```
function onEdit() { changeValue(); }
 
 function changeValue(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var targetDate = sheet.getRange('A3').getValue();
   if(!["Monday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday"].includes(targetDate)) { return; } 
  
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange('A7:A30');
  var values = targetRange.getValues();
  for(var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    var value = values[row][0];
    if(value <= 0.05 && value !="") {
      value = 0.01;
      values[row][0] = value;
    }    
  }
  targetRange.setValues(values);
}
```